# asp.net Treeview nodes not retaining Css class on node selection

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, treeview

I am overriding some of the functions of TreeView control of asp.net.In that I am giving a css class to the treeview for the nodes on level 1 or at level 2. And for the rest of nodes I dont need any Css class to be assigned.My Treeview class where I am assigning 'con' css class to nodes is like this :

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

<Serializable()>
Public Class Node
    Inherits TreeNode

    Public Property NodeID As Integer

    Public Property NodeType As enumNodeTypes

    Public Property NodeParentID As Integer

    Public Property StatusColor As ColorStatus

    Public Property NodeName As String
        Get
            Return Me.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            'Me.Text = value
            Me.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property NodeValue As String
        Get
            Return Me.Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property NodeDataSource As List(Of Node)

    Public Property NodeImageUrl As String
        Get
            Return Me.ImageUrl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.ImageUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property NodeNavigateUrl As String
        Get
            Return Me.NavigateUrl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.NavigateUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property NodeTarget As String
        Get
            Return Me.Target
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.Target = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property NodeToolTip As String
        Get
            Return Me.ToolTip

        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.ToolTip = value
        End Set
    End Property



    'Private _CssClass As String
    'Public Property CssClass As String
    '    Get
    '        Return _CssClass
    '    End Get
    '    Set(ByVal value As String)
    '        _CssClass = value
    '    End Set
    'End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strValue As String, ByVal intNodeType As enumNodeTypes)
        MyBase.New(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strText), strValue)
        Me.NodeValue = intNodeType & ";" & strValue
        NodeName = strText
        NodeDataSource = New List(Of Node)
    End Sub

    '------- Added for Highrise Engineering ------------
    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strValue As String, ByVal intNodeType As enumNodeTypes, ByVal strNodeImageURL As String, ByVal strTreeID As String)
        MyBase.New(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strText), strValue)
        Me.NodeValue = intNodeType & ";" & strValue & ";" & strTreeID
        Me.NodeImageUrl = strNodeImageURL
        NodeName = strText
        NodeDataSource = New List(Of Node)

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strValue As String, ByVal intNodeType As enumNodeTypes, ByVal strNodeImageURL As String)
        MyBase.New(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strText), strValue)
        Me.NodeValue = intNodeType & ";" & strValue
        Me.NodeImageUrl = strNodeImageURL
        NodeName = strText
        NodeDataSource = New List(Of Node)
    End Sub
    '----------------------------------------------------

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strValue As String, ByVal objSalesStatus As ColorStatus, ByVal intNodeType As enumNodeTypes)
        MyBase.New(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strText), strValue)
        'NodeValue = strValue
        Me.NodeValue = intNodeType & ";" & strValue
        NodeName = strText
        NodeDataSource = New List(Of Node)

        'objSaleStatus = New ColorStatus(1, "TempBooked", Drawing.Color.Red)
        '                ElseIf eachUnit.UnitSaleStatus = 5 Then

        '                ElseIf eachUnit.UnitSaleStatus = 3 Then
        'objSaleStatus = New ColorStatus(1, "AgrrNotDoneSaleNotLock", Drawing.Color.SkyBlue)
        '                ElseIf eachUnit.UnitSaleStatus = 8 Then
        'objSaleStatus = New ColorStatus(1, "AgrrNotDoneSaleLock", Drawing.Color.SkyBlue) 'Skybluewithlock(image)
        '                ElseIf eachUnit.UnitSaleStatus = 7 Then
        'objSaleStatus = New ColorStatus(1, "AgrrDoneSaleLock", Drawing.Color.DarkBlue) 'DarkBluewithlock(image)
        '                ElseIf eachUnit.UnitSaleStatus = 6 Then
        'objSaleStatus = New ColorStatus(1, "AgrrDoneSaleNotLock", Drawing.Color.DarkBlue) 'DarkBlue(image)
        '                Else
        'objSaleStatus = New ColorStatus(1, "TempBooked", Drawing.Color.Red)

        Select Case objSalesStatus.StatusName
            Case "TempBooked"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\10_Unsold.png"

            Case "Hold"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\20_On-Hold.PNG"

            Case "TempTillDateBooked"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\30_Temp-Booked.png"

            Case "Booking"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\40_Booking.png"

            Case "AgrrNotDoneSaleNotLock"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\50_Sold.png"

            Case "AgrrDoneSaleNotLock"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\60_Agreement.png"








                'Anjali: for 13.0.12
                '-------------------

                '---------------------


            Case "AgrrNotDoneSaleLock"
                'Anjali: for 13.0.12: changed image
                '-----------------------------------
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\50_Sold.png"
                '---------------------

            Case "AgrrDoneSaleLock"
                'Anjali: for 13.0.12: changed image
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\50_Sold.png"
                '----------------------



                'Anjali: for 13.0.12
                '----------------------

            Case "BookingPSNotAttached"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\50_Sold.png"
            Case "Freeze"
                Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\50_Sold.png"
                '----------------------

                '13.0.25
                '-------

                '-------


                'Case "TempBooked"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\HOUSE.bmp"
                '    'Anjali: for 13.0.12
                '    '-------------------
                'Case "TempTillDateBooked"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\HouseTemporaryTillDateBooking.png"
                '    '---------------------
                'Case "AgrrNotDoneSaleNotLock"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\SoldHouse.bmp"

                'Case "AgrrNotDoneSaleLock"
                '    'Anjali: for 13.0.12: changed image
                '    '-----------------------------------
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\SoldHouseLock.png"
                '    '---------------------

                'Case "AgrrDoneSaleLock"
                '    'Anjali: for 13.0.12: changed image
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\SoldHouseAggDoneLock.png"
                '    '----------------------

                'Case "AgrrDoneSaleNotLock"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\SoldHouseAggDone.bmp"

                '    'Anjali: for 13.0.12
                '    '----------------------
                'Case "Booking"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\HouseBooking.png"
                'Case "BookingPSNotAttached"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\HouseBookingLock.png"
                'Case "Freeze"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\HouseFreeze.png"
                '    '----------------------

                '    '13.0.25
                '    '-------
                'Case "Hold"
                '    Me.NodeImageUrl = "~\Images\House_OnHold.PNG"
                '    '-------
        End Select

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strValue As String, ByVal strImageURL As String, ByVal strNavigateURL As String, ByVal strTarget As String, ByVal intNodeType As enumNodeTypes)
        MyBase.New(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strText), strValue, strImageURL, strNavigateURL, strTarget)
        'NodeValue = strValue
        Me.NodeValue = intNodeType & ";" & strValue
        Me.NodeName = strText
        Me.NodeImageUrl = strImageURL
        Me.NodeNavigateUrl = strNavigateURL
        Me.NodeTarget = strTarget
        'Me.NodeType = intNodeType


        NodeDataSource = New List(Of Node)

    End Sub


    'Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(ByVal savedState As Object)
    '    If savedState IsNot Nothing Then
    '        Dim myState() As Object = CType(savedState, Object())
    '        If myState(0) IsNot Nothing Then
    '            MyBase.LoadViewState(myState(0))
    '        End If
    '        If myState(1) IsNot Nothing Then
    '            CssClass = myState(1).ToString
    '        End If
    '    End If
    'End Sub

    'Protected Overrides Function SaveViewState() As Object
    '    Dim baseState As Object = MyBase.SaveViewState()
    '    Dim allStates(3) As Object
    '    allStates(0) = baseState
    '    allStates(1) = CssClass
    '    Return allStates
    'End Function
    Protected Sub Load(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        Dim sbCss As New Text.StringBuilder
        If (
            Me.Depth < 3 And Me.Depth > 0) Then
            writer.AddAttribute("class", "con")
        End If


    End Sub

    Protected Sub Init(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        Dim sbCss As New Text.StringBuilder
        If (
            Me.Depth < 3 And Me.Depth > 0) Then
            writer.AddAttribute("class", "con")
        End If


    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RenderPreText(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        'writer.AddAttribute("href", "")

        ''writer.AddAttribute("oncontextmenu", "alert('" & Me.NodeName & "');return false;")
        'Project = 0
        ' Building = 1
        ' Wing = 2
        ' Unit = 3
        'Parking = 5

        If (Me.Depth < 3 And Me.Depth > 0) Then
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "con")


        End If
        'Me.NodeType <> 0 Dim sbMouseDownScript As New Text.StringBuilder
        '   sbMouseDownScript.Append("var rightclick;")
        '   sbMouseDownScript.Append("var e = window.event;")
        '  sbMouseDownScript.Append("if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);")
        '  sbMouseDownScript.Append("else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);")
        'sbMouseDownScript.Append("alert(rightclick);")
        ' sbMouseDownScript.Append("if (rightclick) alert('" & Me.NodeName & "');")
        '  writer.AddAttribute("onmousedown", sbMouseDownScript.ToString)
        'writer.AddAttribute("ondoubleclick", sbTaskClickScript.ToString)

        'writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, Me.CssClass)
        'writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)

        'writer.AddAttribute("class", CssClass)

        'writer.WriteFullBeginTag("div style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:9pt;width: 100%;color:Black'")

        MyBase.RenderPreText(writer)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RenderPostText(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        If (
                 Me.Depth < 3 And Me.Depth > 0) Then
            writer.AddAttribute("class", "con")
        End If
        writer.WriteEndTag("div")
        MyBase.RenderPostText(writer)

    End Sub

End Class

Public Enum enumNodeTypes
    '---DONT CHANGE THE ENUM VALUES

    '---Used for Project-Building-Units Treeview
    Project = 0
    Building = 1
    Wing = 2
    Unit = 3
    Parking = 5

    '---Used for Templates Treeview
    TemplateType = 6
    PaymentScheduleTemplate = 7
    OtherChargesTemplate = 8
    ExtraWorkTemplate = 9
    AgreementOtherCharges = 10

    '---Used for Tasks Treeview
    TaskGroup = 31
    Task = 4

    '------- Added for Highrise Engineering ------------
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '-- Following are just some random constants which are not used earlier in this enum 
    '---They are used only for identifying the node type
    '---These values are not saved in the database

    'Used to identify the Root Node
    Root = 999

    '---Used to identify dummy nodes in the treeview
    Dummy_Materials = 1001
    Dummy_Equipments = 1002
    Dummy_Labours = 1003
    Dummy_QualityChecks = 1004
    Dummy_Requisitions = 1005
    Dummy_WorkOrders = 1006
    Dummy_Dependencies = 1007

    '---Used for Labour Treeview
    LabourGroup = 41
    Labour = 40

    '---Used for Material Treeview
    MaterialGroup = 51
    Material = 50

    '---Used for Equipment Treeview
    EquipmentGroup = 61
    Equipment = 60

    '---Used for Quality Treeview
    QualityCheckGroup = 71
    QualityCheck = 70

    '---Used for Task Treeview
    Requisition = 80
    WorkOrder = 90

    '----------Used for Schedule
    Dependency = 95

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TenderItemGroup = 101
    TenderItem = 102
    TenderItemTask = 103
    '--------------------------
    TenderEnquiryItemGroup = 201
    TenderEnquiryItem = 202
End Enum


Public Enum enumCallingApplication
    HighriseSales
    HighriseEngineering
    HighriseTender
End Enum
```

I am using jquery to apply context menu on the nodes where css class is 'con' but the issue is when I select any node all the other loose css class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '#divLibraryTreeView .con',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
            },
            items: {
                "edit": {
                    name: "Add group",
                    icon: "add",
                    callback: function () { document.getElementById('<%= imgbtnAddNewGroup.ClientID %>').click();   }
                },
                "cut": {
                    name: "Add task",
                    icon: "add",
                    callback: function () { document.getElementById('<%= imgbtnAddNew.ClientID %>').click(); }
                },
                "cancel": {
                    name: "Cancel",
                    icon: "cross",
                    callback: function () { return true; }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was so simple just needed to add cssclass to levels it self like this:

```
               <LevelStyles>
                <asp:TreeNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" />
                <asp:TreeNodeStyle CssClass="con" Font-Underline="False" />
                <asp:TreeNodeStyle CssClass="con" Font-Underline="False" />
                </LevelStyles>
```